# Determining the cardinality of these sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I am having trouble with determining the cardinality(finite, denumerable, uncountable) of these two sets:

1. The set of all circles in $\mathbb{R}^2$ in form $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=R^2$ with $a,b,R\in\mathbb{Q}$.
2. $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x+y\in\mathbb{Q}\}$

Work:I think that both sets are uncountable since they are both infinite subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is an uncountable set.

Comment: There is a flaw in your reasoning. You know that $\mathbb N$ is countable, but it too is an infinite subset of the uncountable set $\mathbb R$, right? You should review what the results of combining countable sets in various ways are, especially the Cartesian product of countable sets. I presume you know that $\mathbb Q$ is also countable.

Comment: You formally show that |A| = |B| by giving a bijection between the sets. Or, alternatively, you can give an injection (which shows that |A| <= |B|) and a surjection (which shows that |A| >= |B|) from A to B.

Comment: @MonKeePoo: While this is correct in the case of a countable set, this need not be true in general if one does not assume the axiom of choice. It is consistent that the axiom of choice fails, and there are sets $A$ and $B$ and functions $f,g$ from $A$ to $B$, where $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective, and still $|A|<|B|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If you don't already have it as a theorem, prove that ${\mathbb N} \times {\mathbb N}$ is countable, and then you will get that the first set is countable. For the second set, consider all pairs of the form $(x,1-x)$ where $x$ is irrational, and show this set is uncountable.

Comment: Also notice that you can write the elements in the first set either as $(a, b, R)$ with $a, b, R \in \mathbb{Q}$ or as $(a, b, R) \in \mathbb{Q^3}$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Note that circle is uniquely determined by $a,b,R$. So there is a natural bijection between the first set and a subset of $\Bbb Q^3$. For the second set, note that for every $x\in\Bbb R$ there is some $y$ such that $x+y=0$.

Comment: It's all about finding bijections, really. Or sometimes an injection and a surjection, if you can't find a bijection.

Comment: And your point is?

Comment: Oh, that statement was pointed more towards OP than towards you. I guess you know that already, haha.

Comment: Then perhaps post it under the question. I thought it was meant as some criticism of my answer... :-P

Comment: That's a better place indeed.